# Where does root :0 2018-03-03 12:24(:0)..come from?

Tags: c++

I know that the putchar('*') writes single character to STDOUT and then returns the character if writing is successful otherwise end of file is returned and that fflush() flushes any butters to underlying file or terminal and that putchar('n'); creates a newline for upcoming text. I also understand the logic behind the outputs for Case 1 and 2

But I don't know where the root: 0 and root pts/2 lines came from?

The output of the following program is:

```
[/root]#./a.out
Type ^C during either Case 1, Case 2, or Case 3Case 1: no special arrangements..**********
Case 2: ignoring interrupts..***^C^C*^C*^C**^C*^C**^C
Case 3: catching interrupts..**^C Ouch! 
root     :0           2018-03-03 12:24 (:0) /* Where does this line come from*/
root     pts/2        2018-03-03 12:26 (:0) /* Where does this line come from*/
```

Code is:

```
  /** sigsample.c  signal sampler
     *  demonstrate how signals can kill a process,
     *  be ignored by a process, or be caught by a process
     **/
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>

void catcher() /* a function to run when a signal is caught */
{
    printf(" Ouch! \n");
    system("who");
}

main()
{
    int i;
    printf("Type ^C during either Case 1, Case 2, or Case 3");
    printf("Case 1: no special arrangements..");
    for (i=0;i<10;i++){
        putchar('*');fflush(stdout);
        sleep(1);
    }
    putchar('\n');

    signal(SIGINT, SIG_IGN);    /* ignore INTerrupts */
    printf("Case 2: ignoring interrupts..");
    for (i=0;i<10;i++){
        putchar('*');fflush(stdout);
        sleep(1);
    }
    putchar('\n');

    signal(SIGINT, catcher);    /* handle interruptions */
    printf("Case 3: catching interrupts..");
    for (i=0;i<10;i++){
        putchar('*');fflush(stdout);
        sleep(1);
    }
    putchar('\n');
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You assigned a handler for `SIGINT`. Then you triggered it by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>.

```
void catcher() /* a function to run when a signal is caught */
{
    printf(" Ouch! \n");
    system("who");
}
```

This function firsts prints the `Ouch` and then calls `who` and sends the contents to STDOUT. That is why you see the lines starting with `root`.